# Hope-DT GTK+ theme displays white fonts after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, themes, gtk

I have recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. On Ocelot I was using the Hope theme tip to install it: [give-your-linux-desktop-new-hope-with-this-gtk3-theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/give-your-linux-desktop-new-hope-with-this-gtk3-theme/)

I especially liked the fact that it turned the Sidebar in Nautilus black, which I found pretty cool.
After the upgrade, all my system fonts are white when I set the GTK+ theme to Hope or Hope-DT. See pic:

[image]

Now, is there any way to force the fonts colour? or, if nothing else works, could you guys suggest a way to turn the Sidebar in Nautilus to black? Any nice dark gtk+ theme suggestions are also welcome.

cheers.

Edit:

From the [Hope theme page](http://grvrulz.deviantart.com/art/Hope-gtk3-206207315?offset=0#comments) I see that in the comments more people are complaining about this issue after upgrading. So, my question now is: any way to control the system font colours? Or please suggest a them which adds black sidebars in nautilus.

Edit 2:

I have installed the .deb file from launchpad: [hope precise](https://launchpad.net/~kokoto-java/+archive/omgubuntu-stuff/+build/3081584)

Unfortunately it did not solve the problem, however, now my Ambience theme is gone.... I can't even find it in /usr/share/themes. And now my entire desktop looks a bit crap. Menus don't seem right.

Can I install the default Ambience theme from somewhere?

Comment: After upgrading to 12.04, I ran into the same problem with a couple of my old themes.  They needed to be upgraded to (I think) in order to work properly with Gnome 3.4.  I went to the creator's website and found a version for Ubuntu 12.04, and it has worked perfectly.  This might be what you need to do, too.  If you access the Launchpad page for it (https://launchpad.net/~kokoto-java/+archive/omgubuntu-stuff/+build/3081584), I think you'll find a version for precise.

Comment: thx mate. I will check it out shortly. But you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kelley](https://askubuntu.com/users/19610/kelley) gave the answer in a comment that I will post as definitive:

*After upgrading to 12.04, I ran into the same problem with a couple of my old themes. They needed to be upgraded to (I think) in order to work properly with Gnome 3.4. I went to the creator's website and found a version for Ubuntu 12.04, and it has worked perfectly. This might be what you need to do, too. If you access the Launchpad page for it ([launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~kokoto-java/+archive/omgubuntu-stuff/+build/3081584)), I think you'll find a version for precise.*

Comment: you may add kelley answer yourself (as proper answer): even i can do it

Comment: @cipricus Thanks's for being thorough, I've added his comment as an answer. I really don't know how to accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: @cipricus, thx. I was too tired to spot the easy obvious solution of linking the user. Thanks for the update.